# jQuery random blockquote

Tags: jquery, arrays, random, quotations, bigcartel

I've spent the past 2 hours looking for and testing various solutions to this problem but to little success so I'm resigned to asking for help.

I would like to build an array of quotes which each have citations and and a link, to be pulled at random. I don't need any thing more than for them to change upon page refresh.

However, I have some pretty tasty CSS to style blockquote and cite.

Here's some example HTML to illustrate how the content from the array would fit within a quote:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>A line of oversize watches that can offer many of the attributes of premium luxury watches at an affordable price.
  </p>
  <cite>&mdash; 
    <a href="http://www.horozima.com/2012/07/terranaut-xl-50mm.html" target="_blank">Horozima
    </a>
  </cite>
</blockquote>
```

The intended location for this code is a Big Cartel product (template) page with automatically generated content for each product. So, without some randomizing JS the same quote would be on every product page.

Comment: what exactly are you asking?  what does CSS have to do with this?  where's your code that shows what you've tried (not what the output needs to look like)?

Comment: Two great answers below, I'll get back later with my choice and any further comments. I chose not to include my trial JS because I thought it was better to gather (better) ideas than to correct what probably wasn't the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute JavaScript on DOMReady to use the [`random()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) function to generate a random number. If you multiply this number by a value you will get a random number between 0 and the value (but not including the value itself). If you put the quotes into a JSON array, you can use the array's `.length` property for the value you multiply by since the number of items in the array is one larger than the index of the last item. This will generate a random number that is one of the indexes of the array.

After this, use jQuery's [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to replace the text of the paragraph and citation tags to display the quote you randomly selected.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/sWvGp/

HTML:

```
<blockquote id="randomquote">
    <p></p> <cite>&mdash; <a href="#" target="_blank"></a></cite>
</blockquote>
```

Javascript:

```
var myQuotes = [{
    quote: "To err is human; to forgive, divine.",
    cite: "Alexander Pope",
    url: "http://www.example.com"
}, {
    quote: "Reports of my death have been greatly exaggerated.",
    cite: "Mark Twain",
    url: "http://www.example.com"
}, {
    quote: "A line of oversize watches that can offer many of the attributes of premium luxury watches at an affordable price.",
    cite: "Horozima",
    url: "http://www.horozima.com/2012/07/terranaut-xl-50mm.html"
}];

var randomQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * myQuotes.length)

$('p', '#randomquote').text(myQuotes[randomQuote].quote);
$('cite a', '#randomquote').attr('href', myQuotes[randomQuote].url).text(myQuotes[randomQuote].cite);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll come back once I've experimented with this. I like the way you've organised the quotes.

Comment: Both examples gained the desired result, but I liked the way you set out the array. Sadly, I don't think either is possible to use because of a conflict with these two JS sources necessary for the Big Cartel store: http://cache1.bigcartel.com/themes/sexy/javascripts/prototype.js and http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52548810/Themes/3925/script.js

Comment: You can avoid conflicts with other libraries using [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/). You can alias the `$()` command to something like `$jQ()`. Hopefully this will solve your issue.

Comment: I have just tested my extensive but offline trial and that's working. Will feedback tomorrow once I update the Big Cartel site. Thanks Corion!

Comment: Just to let you known, everything worked great once uploaded to the Big Cartel server. Thanks a lot Corion.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your strengths, you can do it "quick and dirty" or as a proper solution.

The proper solution would be to have server side some code that pulls a random row from a database, and renders it as above. Since your tags have nothing to do with it, I'll skip on to

the quick and dirty solution, which is to have a javascript array of quotes and links, and a random one shown:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var questions = [
      {q: 'This is question 1', l: 'http://this.is.link1', a: 'Test' },
      {q: 'This is question 2', l: 'http://this.is.link2' , a:'Another'}
  ];

  var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*questions.length));

  $('blockquote p').html(questions[i].q);
  $('blockquote a').attr('href', questions[i].l);
  $('blockquote a').html(questions[i].a);
});
```

You can see that live in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWauh/1/). It assumes only a single blockquote is present, but it can be easily extended. You can output a single quote in your HTML to make it look ok when JS is disabled.

Comment: Bah. You beat me to the fiddle. :0)

Comment: I believe `.attr('src'` should be `.attr('href'`

Comment: @Corion: true, too used in using this type of code for images I'm afraid. Edited.

Comment: Just noticed another: `questions.length` is already 1 greater than the number of quotes, so adding +1 occasionally sends you out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll come back once I've experimented with this.